# update view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm making an app where I'm programmatically moving an image around the screen by reading a CGPoint from an array and setting the center of the image accordingly. In the most simple form it's like this:

```
for point in array {
     image.center = point
     sleep(1)
}
```

It happens after pressing a button so the for-loop is inside the `@IBAction func ...` of the button.

The problem is that the screen isn't updating after an `image.center` change, but only after the whole for-loop is done, so when the image is at the last point in the array. How do I force the view to update? Or what is the best way to deal with this in general?

Comment: Maybe try a CAKeyframeAnimation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use keyframe animation.
Lets assume this is your points:

```
let val: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x:10, y:20), CGPoint(x:100, y:80), CGPoint(x:200, y:80), CGPoint(x:200, y:400), CGPoint(x:30, y:400), CGPoint(x:30, y:100)]
```

After you press button you call animation:

```
       let duration = NSTimeInterval(2)

        UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: nil, animations: {

            self.myView.center = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)

            for (index, point) in enumerate(self.val) {
                UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(Double(index) *  1.0 / Double(self.val.count), relativeDuration: 1.0 / Double(self.val.count), animations: {
                    self.myView.center = point
                })
            }
        }, completion: nil)
```

Of course you can customise your animation duration, delay and so on.
Just remember in

```
UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime relativeDuration...
```

there are relative values so for example duration should be between 0-1 where 1 is your total duration you specified in

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration...
```

Comment: For all those making something similar to what I'm trying, you can set `frameDuration` of the `addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime` to 0 if you don't want it to be animated. Took me a few hours to realise that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sleep as @matt advised and try to call the method layoutifneeded on the parent view of your image instead of the sleep. The view needs to be redrawn, so I think this could make the trick...

Comment: what would be the best way to delay the next iteration of the for-loop then?

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do this is to use animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: and use the delay parameter to give you what delay you want between moves. The following code starts the first move  immediately, then each subsequent one after one second.

**Swift 2**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var block = UIView()
    var pointArray = [CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30), CGPoint(x: 100, y: 30), CGPoint(x: 50, y: 300), CGPoint(x: 300, y: 170)]
    var counter = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        block.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        block.center = pointArray[0]
        block.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view.addSubview(block)
        moveView()
    }

    func moveView() {
        var delay = counter == 1 ? Double(0) : Double(1)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: delay, options: .CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.block.center = self.pointArray[self.counter]
        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            self.counter++
            if self.counter < self.pointArray.count {
                self.moveView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var block = UIView()
    var pointArray = [CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30), CGPoint(x: 100, y: 30), CGPoint(x: 50, y: 300), CGPoint(x: 300, y: 170)]
    var counter = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        block.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        block.center = pointArray[0]
        block.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        view.addSubview(block)
        moveView()
    }

    func moveView() {
        let delay = counter == 1 ? Double(0) : Double(1)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: delay, options: .curveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.block.center = self.pointArray[self.counter]
        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            self.counter+=1
            if self.counter < self.pointArray.count {
                self.moveView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Greg's way is better/easier because it achieves the same thing where his method is obviously ment to do that what he achieves with it